# Jenkins: Jenkins not running TestNG Tests

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file, jenkins

I am able to successfully execute TestNG script but while I am trying to execute the same using Jenkins, it shows the following:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\Users\user\Desktop\xyz
[xyz] $ cmd /c call C:\windows\TEMP\hudson1998633505158708122.bat

C:\Users\user\Desktop\xyz>run.bat

C:\Users\user\Desktop\xyz>java -cp bin;lib/* org.testng.TestNG testng.xml 
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\user\Desktop\xyz\testng.xml

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Test case 1 is end

===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Skips: 3
===============================================

Finished: SUCCESS
```

However, I am able to execute `bat` file and TestNG script successfully as below is the TestNG report:

[image]

Why does it skip all 3 test cases?

Comment: Did you check testng report on why the tests are skipped.

Comment: TestNG report shows all 3 cases as Pass

Comment: can you delete the file and run again from jenkins it should not be showing or pass this is just to make sure you are looking into the right report

Comment: also set verbose ="10" in testng.xml to see why it is skipping

Comment: Hey, Vikas, Thanks. I could debug using verbose and resolved it!

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: jxl jar file was missing and error was: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jxl/read/biff/BiffException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use verbose="10" to check why it is skipping the tests.